# #Ruby Tk passing method/functions as arguments

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, tk-toolkit

I explain:

I would like to know how I can pass method or functions as arguments.

> For example, in **Python** will be:

```
from MyFile import MyClass

MyClass().my_method_click(function)  # without parentheses
```

> In this example, in **Python** you send the functions or method without
>   parentheses, if I do:

```
from MyFile import MyClass

MyClass().my_method_click(function())  # with parentheses
```

I call the function but don't send it.

> In **Ruby**, when you call a method or function, you can do it with or
>   without parentheses.
>
> if I do this in Ruby:

```
require_relative "MyClass"

MyClass.new.my_method_click(function) # without parentheses
```

Just call it without send it.

Of course, is for a Button, that when I click it, run this operation.

**How I can do it in Ruby??**

**Thanks!**

Comment: Your question is unclear. You talk about methods and functions as if they were interchangeable, but methods and functions are very different things. Methods belong to objects, but aren't themselves objects. Functions *are* objects. Ruby doesn't have a concept of "function". Depending on what *exactly* you mean, the role of "function" could be played by any of the following: a `Proc`, an object which responds to `call`, an object which responds to `to_proc`, or an object which responds to `call` *and* `to_proc`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to pass a runnable block of code. I haven't looked into Python yet, but I am sure it supports closures as well.

Anyhow, in Ruby, a "general" way of passing a runnable code is to use blocks (lambdas and procs).

```
function = lambda { # your code }
MyClass.new.my_method_click(function)

# or a shorter way
MyClass.new.my_method_click(-> { # your code })

# to run a block
def my_method_click(&block)
    #you can either `yield` from your receiving method
    yield

    # or call `.call` method on your lambda/proc instance
    block.call
end
```

You can also get an instance of your class' method or create a new method one using `Method.new`. But, you'd end up dealing with bindings and binding to the correct instance types, etc. So, it's much easier with `Lambda`s and `Proc`s.